# Why is my OnSelectedIndexChanged not triggering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, events, event-handling

I have two `<select>` controls being used as dropdowns: one with a collection of cities, and the other with a list of hotels. What I would like is that, when the user changes the selected city, the hotels dropdown updates to only show hotels in that city. The drowpdown with the cities is populating successfully; however, I can't seem to get an event to fire when the city is changed.

Here is my CSHTML for the city dropdown. Note the `AutoPostBack="True"` tag:

```
      <label asp-for="Destinations" class="col-sm-3">
        Destination
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select runat="server"
                id="destinationDropdown"
                name="destinationDropdown"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="destinationDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                style="width:240px">
          @foreach (Destination destination in Model.Destinations){
            <option value="@destination.DestinationId" id="@destination.DestinationId">@destination.DestinationName</option>
          }
        </select>
      </div>Th
```

Here is my C# code:

```
    protected void destinationDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Do work here
      ...
    }
```

I say that the event isn't firing, rather than a problem with the hotels dropdown, because I've put a breakpoint on the first line of code in the methods, and it doesn't get hit.

I've searched on this site for help, and it seems like the majority of solutions are to include the `AutoPostBack="True"` tag, which I already have.

**Edit:** I've been informed in the comments that `AutoPostBack` is a WebForms approach, which is why it doesn't work in my MVC site. I would still like to know if there is a way to make this work in MVC. I can either edit this question, or start a new one, as appropriate.

Comment: is it a MVC site? you've taged asp.net-mvc. mvc does not support "AutoPostBack". what you are doing is for WebForms, not MVC

Comment: @Trekco This is an MVC site. I'm not familiar with the differences between MVC and WebForms, so I didn't realize that I've been trying WebForms approaches. That at least explains why my `AutoPostBack` wasn't working.

Comment: please mark my answer as an answer @TheTwoArmedMan

Comment: It looks like you could use a good tutorial on ASP.NET MVC, it is quite different to WebForms. Try the Microsoft one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: This tutorial shows what you are trying to do, it's doing more than you as it's setting up the database and entity model. The main part that relates to you is under the Controller and View sections...  [Populate one DropDownList based on another DropDownLists selection](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-one-DropDownList-based-on-another-DropDownList-selected-value-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a MVC site then `runat="server"`, `AutoPostBack="True"` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged="destinationDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged"` attributes will not work. It will only work on a WebForm Site

Comment: Why was this down-voted the OP asked why it was not working and i believe that @Trekco answered that?